# Returning a users directory profile with the Admin SDK on Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

Need some GAS help..

I am trying to return a list of users and their department using the ADMIN SDK 
Using Google Apps Script and the Directory API in the Admin SDK.

```
if (users) {
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    values.push([users[i].primaryEmail, users[i].orgUnitPath, users[i].organizations.department]);
  }
```

I cannot figure out the syntax to return the department in the organizations.department

If I use 
**users[i].organizations**
Then it returns every available entry in organization for that user.

Ex.

```
[{title=Student, location=3, customType=work, department=School, primary=true, name=School District}]
```

I need to return just 'department'

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, there is no way to get department directly. You need iterate each organization entry to get department. [see here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get#try-it) in fields text-field, you can select fields that you want to see in output(response)